# #1054 - Unknown column 'proximite' in 'where clause' in MySQL

Tags: mysql

When running the query below, I end up with a MYSQL error in PHPMyAdmin:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'proximite' in 'where clause'

i m using mysql 5.6 and phpMyAdmin i have an error with Proximite,please i need a help
Looking for example the 10 closest restaurants of the Eiffel Tower in Paris (latitude: 48.858205, longitude: 2.294359) and whose distance is less than 1 km.
The database contains a table "restaurants". This table contains, among other fields "lat" and "lng" corresponding to the latitude and longitude of the restaurant
this is my try:

```
SELECT *, get_distance_metres('48.858205', '2.294359', lat, lng) 
  AS proximite 
  FROM restaurants 
  WHERE proximite < 1000 ORDER BY proximite ASC 
  LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant use that alias in the `WHERE` clause of the *same* query.

Try this:

```
SELECT *, get_distance_metres('48.858205', '2.294359', lat, lng) 
  AS proximite 
  FROM restaurants 
  WHERE get_distance_metres('48.858205', '2.294359', lat, lng) < 1000
  ORDER BY proximite ASC 
  LIMIT 10
```

Doc:

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

**[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)**

Comment: More info about SQL's [order of operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm)

Comment: it return me null ligne :"MySQL a retourné un résultat vide (aucune ligne)"

Comment: it reurn just when I put great value in the condition(100000) ,butI want restaurants just lower  1km (1000 m)